# Category to be hidden when check on top in Opencart 1.5.2.1

Tags: opencart

I need some help in Opencart 1.5.2.1. I want to make a category in left bar.

I want to put in toolbar (on top from category). When I put on top, iy is in top but it is also in menu from left side.

I want when I put to on top, I want to be that category only on top and be hidden in menu from left.

Comment: Usually when question is like 'i want', it goes against the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). If you can specify a problem, you will more likely get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is: You only want to show those categories on left menu which are not at top menu.

There's no default functionality to do this via Admin. You can only set Top option ON or OFF for categories. You'll need to code a new function (ex: `getCategorisNotOnTop()`) in catalog/category model to be used in module/category controller and call it instead of default getCategories() function.

Like: Change

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

to:

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategorisNotOnTop(0);
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Thanks but you can be exactly? Where i can d this in what;s files. can you tell me the path?
Thanks

Comment: Write a new function in `/catalog/model/catalog/category.php`. And use that function (as explained in my answer) in file `/catalog/controller/module/category.php`